# Error using the forecast function with the ets or nntar function

Tags: r, forecasting, ets

I am trying to use the `forecast()` function in R on different ETS objects or NNTAR. I get the same error message everytime.

```r
ets_model <- ets(trainingdata)

ets_forecast.pred <- forecast(ets_model, h=10)
```

I get the following error message:

> "Error in UseMethod("forecast") :
> no applicable method for 'forecast' applied to an object of class "ets""

The same problem occurs with nntar object to neural network and I use auto.arima function:

> no applicable method for 'forecast' applied to an object of class "c('forecast_ARIMA', 'ARIMA', 'Arima')"

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem can be solved by reinstalling the packages again. There was probably a problem or inconsistency. I hope the answer can help others who may have the same problem. Thanks for the personal space. Goodbye.

Comment: It's more likely that you loaded a package that over-wrote the `forecast` function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Probably the problem was this error
Rob Hyndman. I usually install the packages in the first part of the code. When doing some specific analysis, I must have installed some package that also had the forecast function, but with other properties. Thank you very much for your attention.